# Asp.net MVC 4 and FormsAuthentication.User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

Im trying to use FormsAuthentication in asp.net MVC 4 application.
The authentication itself works fine, but whenever Im getting the User from FormsAuthenticationEventArgs.User and assign to Http.Context.Current.User it works at that exactly moment and next call method bellow Http.Context.Current.User is null again...
What am I doing wrong?

```
protected void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
    {

        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
                    var usuarioRn = new UsuarioRN();
                    string roles = usuarioRn.GetRoles(username);

                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket =  FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);

                    e.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new   System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity(ticket), roles.Split(';'));
                    //First time get here assign e.User to HttpContext.Current.User, all good
                    //Next call HttpContext.Current.User is again null, why?
                    HttpContext.Current.User = e.User;                       
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why would you assign the user this way?  FormsAuthentication populates the HttpContext.Current.User without this.  Another note - the Context.User in MVC is not the same as HttpContext.Current.User.  Can you post the code when you are calling to access the user?

Comment: I'm driving right now, ASAP I'll post the code.

Comment: @ramires.cabral - you should really be using Application_AuthenticateRequest rather than FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate

Answer (score 0):

[FormsAuthenticationEventArgs.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationeventargs.user%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is just so you can set the User property of the current HttpContext to a custom IPrincipal object.

It would probably be a lot easier to understand if it had this signature:

```
FormsAuthenticationEventArgs.SetHttpContextUser(IPrinciple user);
```

In other words, it will always be null - it actually sets something else (the HttpContext User) when you assign something to it.